# style.map() returning different values when queried twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I was looking into the style.map() function. I've been reading Python GUI Programming with Tkinter and he mentions that if you call style.map('Treeview') (or whatever type), it should return the current state mappings.

Now when I run it the first time I get this:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.map('Treeview')
{'foreground': [('disabled', 'SystemGrayText'), ('!disabled', '!selected', 'SystemWindowText'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlightText')], 'background': [('disabled', 'SystemButtonFace'), ('!disabled', '!selected', 'SystemWindow'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlight')]}
```

This returns tuples with states and current property as expected.

Now if I were to call it again:

```
s.map('Treeview')
{'foreground': ['disabled', 'SystemGrayText', '!disabled !selected', 'SystemWindowText', 'selected', 'SystemHighlightText'], 'background': ['disabled', 'SystemButtonFace', '!disabled !selected', 'SystemWindow', 'selected', 'SystemHighlight']}
```

Now it's just a single list of states/properties.

I tried going through the documentation and got a bit lost in attempting to do so. One thing I did notice was looking it calls a *_splitdict* function which originally returns key/value pairs for each property. When I print out the key/value pairs it looks like:

```
-foreground (<string object: 'disabled'>, 'SystemGrayText', <string object: '!disabled !selected'>, 'SystemWindowText', <string object: 'selected'>, 'SystemHighlightText')
-background (<string object: 'disabled'>, 'SystemButtonFace', <string object: '!disabled !selected'>, 'SystemWindow', <string object: 'selected'>, 'SystemHighlight')
```

The second time I run style.map() the angle brackets are missing:

```
-foreground ('disabled', 'SystemGrayText', '!disabled !selected', 'SystemWindowText', 'selected', 'SystemHighlightText')
-background ('disabled', 'SystemButtonFace', '!disabled !selected', 'SystemWindow', 'selected', 'SystemHighlight')
```

Is this intentional and how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I literally call `x.map('Treeview')` twice, one right after the other, both calls return identical values. No matter how many times I call it, I get the same values. Are you certain you aren't running any calls between the two invocations of `s.map`?

Comment: @BryanOakley ~ I can verify it. I get 2 different results and absolutely no calls between. I even tried calling it like this twice in a row ~ `print(ttk.Style().map('Treeview'))`. I got the same results.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, there's nothing in between the calls. I'm running this on Windows 10 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you if it is intentional, but I can prove that the second version does not work. I made a simple custom theme. In that theme I created 2 styles for a `ttk.Button`, each using a version of the `map` return. The second version throws an error.

As far as "how is it supposed to work?", the below also examples that. Basically, it's a way to custom color certain options for various states.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from collections import namedtuple

Theme_t = namedtuple('Theme_t', 'Base Primer Topcoat SubContrast Contrast Trim Hilight Accent Flat Gloss')
Theme = Theme_t('#bFbFbF', '#AFAFAF', '#C4C4C4', '#666666', '#888888', '#777777', '#444444', '#313131', '#2C2C2C', '#CCCCCC')
#YOURTHEME = Theme_t('#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#')


@dataclass
class Button_dc:
    foreground:         str = Theme.Hilight
    background:         str = Theme.Topcoat 
    bordercolor:        str = Theme.Base 
    darkcolor:          str = Theme.Base
    lightcolor:         str = Theme.Base 
    highlightcolor:     str = Theme.Base
    relief:             str = 'flat'
    compound:           str = 'left'
    highlightthickness: int = 0
    shiftrelief:        int = 0
    width:              int = 0
    padding = [1,1,1,1] #l,t,r,b
    font:               str = "Consolas 12"
    anchor:             str = 'nswe'


class CustomTheme(ttk.Style):
    def __init__(self, basetheme='clam'):
        ttk.Style.__init__(self)
            
        self.theme_create('custom', basetheme, {
            'custom.TButton': { 
                #default 'normal' style
                'configure': asdict(Button_dc()),
                #style alterations for various button states
                'map': {
                    'background':  [('active', Theme.Primer), ('pressed', Theme.Topcoat)],
                    'foreground':  [('active', Theme.Hilight), ('pressed', Theme.Accent)],
                }
            },
            #this does not work
            #'cust.TButton': { 
            #    'configure': asdict(Button_dc()),
            #    'map': {
            #        'background':  ['active', Theme.Primer, 'pressed', Theme.Topcoat],
            #        'foreground':  ['active', Theme.Hilight, 'pressed', Theme.Accent],
            #    }
            #}
        })
        
        self.theme_use('custom')
        
        
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        CustomTheme()
        
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button 1", style='custom.TButton').grid()
        #ttk.Button(self, text="Button 2", style='cust.TButton').grid()


if "__main__" == __name__:
    app = App()
    app.title("Custom Theme Experiment And Example")
    app.geometry('800x600')
    app.mainloop()
```